# Any tricks to finish integrating?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

I'm working on the following integral:

$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{y^r}{\theta}ry^{r-1}e^{\frac{-y^r}{\theta}} dy$.

I noticed that if I took the derivative:

$\frac{d}{dy}e^{\frac{-y^r}{\theta}} = \frac{-ry^{r-1}}{\theta}e^{\frac{-y^r}{\theta}}$

I got most of the expression of the integrand. But I'm left with an extra factor of $y^r$:

$\int_0^{\infty}(y^r\frac{d}{dy}e^{\frac{-y^r}{\theta}}) dy$

I'm not sure how to simplify this anymore, so is this how I'm supposed to be going about this, or is there another way to take this integral?

I got this from *Wackerly's Mathematical Statistics 7e* when trying to find the $E[Y^r]$ from the following distribution:

$f(y|\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}ry^{r-1}e^{\frac{-y^r}{\theta}}, \theta>0,y>0$

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

with $x = y^r$ : $$r \int_0^\infty y^a e^{-y^r/s}dy =r\int_0^\infty x^{a/r} e^{-x/s}\frac{x^{1/r-1}dx}{r} = \int_0^\infty x^{(a+1)/r-1} e^{-x/s}dx$$ and with $t = x/s$, if $s > 0$ $$= s^{(a+1)/r} \int_0^\infty t^{(a+1)/r-1} e^{-t}dt= s^{(a+1)/r} \Gamma((a+1)/r)$$ if $s \in \mathbb{C}$,  it stays true for $Re(s) > 0$ by [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{r}{\theta} y^{2r-1}e^{-y^r /\theta} \mathbb{d}y = \int_0^\infty y^r \frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{d}y}e^{-y^r/\theta} \mathbb{d}y = y^r e^{-y^r/\theta} \Bigg|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty ry^{r-1}e^{-y^r/\theta} \mathbb{d}y = \theta e^{-y^r/\theta} \Bigg|_0^\infty = \theta $$